# Rule of fail2ban not working when the request is from the brute force attack

Tags: nginx, iptables, firewall, hacking, fail2ban

I have a situation where some IP from moldova try everyday discover my basic auth credentials with some type of brute force attack.

However I have a rule with fail2ban that should avoid this situation. And it works when I try with a VPN.

Example of request that trigger fail2ban after three attempts. My requests

```
2016/07/14 15:10:54 [error] 13937#0: *55700 user "engineer" was not found in "/usr/local/nginx/.htpasswd", client: 146.185.31.214, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mysite.pt"
```

The problem is that, the request from the hacker IP will not trigger the fail2ban, and I don't know why. The only difference is the `referrer:` as you can see.

```
2016/07/14 01:54:31 [error] 13913#0: *42558 user "engineer" was not found in "/usr/local/nginx/.htpasswd", client: 194.28.112.51, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mysite.pt", referrer: "http://www.mysite.pt/
```

---

```
/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/nginx-http-auth.conf

[Definition]


failregex = ^ \[error\] \d+#\d+: \*\d+ user "\S+":? (password mismatch|was not found in ".*"), client: <HOST>, server: \S+, request: "\S+ \S+ HTTP/\d+\.\d+", host: "\S+"\s*$
            ^ \[error\] \d+#\d+: \*\d+ no user/password was provided for basic authentication, client: <HOST>, server: \S+, request: "\S+ \S+ HTTP/\d+\.\d+", host: "\S+"\s*$

ignoreregex =
```

---

```
[nginx-http-auth]

enabled = true
filter  = nginx-http-auth
port    = http,https
logpath = /usr/local/nginx/localhost-error.log
maxretry = 3
```

So the question is why my requests trigger the rule, and the requests from the attacker not?

Excerpt from the log:

```
2016/07/14 01:54:27 [error] 13917#0: *42529 user "mts" was not found in "/usr/local/nginx/.htpasswd", client: 194.28.112.51, server: localhost,  request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mysite.pt", referrer: "http://www.mysite.pt/"
2016/07/14 01:54:27 [error] 13917#0: *42530 user "mts" was not found in "/usr/local/nginx/.htpasswd", client: 194.28.112.51, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mysite.pt", referrer: "http://www.mysite.pt/"
2016/07/14 01:54:28 [error] 13917#0: *42531 user "telecomadmin" was not found in "/usr/local/nginx/.htpasswd", client: 194.28.112.51, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mysite.pt", referrer: "http://www.mysite.pt/"
2016/07/14 01:54:28 [error] 13917#0: *42532 user "telecomadmin" was not found in "/usr/local/nginx/.htpasswd", client: 194.28.112.51, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mysite.pt", referrer: "http://www.mysite.pt/"
2016/07/14 01:54:28 [error] 13917#0: *42533 user "mgts" was not found in "/usr/local/nginx/.htpasswd", client: 194.28.112.51, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mysite.pt", referrer: "http://www.mysite.pt/"
2016/07/14 01:54:28 [error] 13917#0: *42534 user "mgts" was not found in "/usr/local/nginx/.htpasswd", client: 194.28.112.51, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mysite.pt", referrer: "http://www.mysite.pt/"
2016/07/14 01:54:28 [error] 13917#0: *42535 user "admin" was not found in "/usr/local/nginx/.htpasswd", client: 194.28.112.51, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mysite.pt", referrer: "http://www.mysite.pt/"
2016/07/14 01:54:28 [error] 13917#0: *42536 user "admin" was not found in "/usr/local/nginx/.htpasswd", client: 194.28.112.51, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mysite.pt", referrer: "http://www.mysite.pt/"
2016/07/14 01:54:29 [error] 13917#0: *42539 user "kyivstar" was not found in "/usr/local/nginx/.htpasswd", client: 194.28.112.51, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mysite.pt", referrer: "http://www.mysite.pt/"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if the following it too generic for you (if so, please post a comment accordingly), but your given regex doesn't match the `host: ...` value of the log generated by the attacker, specifically the `/` inside there.

You could try out this instead:

```
failregex = ^ \[error\] \d+#\d+: \*\d+ user "\S+":? (password mismatch|was not found in ".*"), client: <HOST>, server: \S+, request: "\S+ \S+ HTTP/\d+\.\d+", host: ".*"$
            ^ \[error\] \d+#\d+: \*\d+ no user/password was provided for basic authentication, client: <HOST>, server: \S+, request: "\S+ \S+ HTTP/\d+\.\d+", host: ".*"$
```